# How to check which process is using write protected mode on file?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, process

I have file which is opend with write protection for some process. Is there a simple way to check which process set write protection on that file in Windows Xp ?

Any tool ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx